# re.sub() does not return ideal output (python2)

Tags: python, regex

I want to replace all the /x** in one string. For example a string like this:

`>>> t
'\n\xd6#\n\xdf\x02\n\x08abstract\x12\xd2\x02\n'`

And I know re.sub can work on the raw text like this:

`>>> re.sub(r'\\x[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}', '', r'\n\xd6#\n\xdf\x02\n\x08abstract\x12\xd2\x02\n')
'\\n#\\n\\nabstract\\n'`

However, if I put t there, then it returns the original text without replacing:

`>>> re.sub(r'\\x[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}', '', t)
'\n\xd6#\n\xdf\x02\n\x08abstract\x12\xd2\x02\n'`

I thought it might be because t here is not raw text and I try to convert it to raw text by (correct me if I'm wrong)

`>>> t.replace("\\","\\\\")
'\n\xd6#\n\xdf\x02\n\x08abstract\x12\xd2\x02\n'`

However as you can see it does not return something like this:

`>>> r'\n\xd6#\n\xdf\x02\n\x08abstract\x12\xd2\x02\n'
'\\n\\xd6#\\n\\xdf\\x02\\n\\x08abstract\\x12\\xd2\\x02\\n'`

So is the sub failing to replace because I'm not passing the str correctly? (I actually do see in some example it works with the original str)

Thanks!

Comment: When entering an expression in the interactive shell, the `repr()` of the result is returned, so e.g. `'\xdf'` really means the single character (or byte) with hexadecimal value df.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thanks for the comment. So if I want to get rows of data from a file and organize them in a list. What can I do in the middle so that the final data would be clean without these \x** when I feed them to some nlp model? I mean when I type `data[0]` it returns a str without \x** ?

Comment: Roughly the regex should be something like (single backslashes!) `re.sub(r'[\x00-\x09\x0b-\x19\x80-\xff]+', '', t)`

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thanks so much!